Prove or disprove that the limit of subsequence infima equals the limit of sequence

Consider some convergent bounded sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Define the sequence $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by $b_n=\inf\{a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2},\cdots\}$. Assume this infimum exists. Prove or disprove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$.

I have proven that the sequence $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing and bounded above, meaning that it must have a limit at its supremum. I have also proven that the limits are the same in the case where $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing, but I do not know how to prove this in the general case, especially where $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent but not monotone. How should I continue my proof?

Hint: Prove that if $L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$, then $L-\epsilon\leq b_n<L+\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

'Convergent bounded sequence' sounds strange. All convergent sequences are bounded.

Yes. We have that $\lim_{n}a_{n}=\lim_{n}b_{n}$, provided
that $\lim_{n}a_{n}$ exists. Let $l=\lim_{n}a_{n}$. Here, we consider
the case $l\in\mathbb{R}$ only. (acutally, the equality continues
to hold if $l=+\infty$ or $l=-\infty$)
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary, then there exists $N$ such that
$a_{n}\in(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)$ whenever $n\geq N$. For
$n\geq N$, $a_{n}\geq l-\varepsilon$ implies that $b_{n}=\inf\{a_{n},a_{n+1},\ldots\}\geq l-\varepsilon$.
Moreover, for $n\geq N$, $b_{n}=\inf\{a_{n},a_{n+1},\ldots\}\leq a_{n}\leq l+\varepsilon$.
This shows that $l-\varepsilon\leq b_{n}\leq l+\varepsilon$. As $(b_{n})$
is monotonic increasing and bounded above by $l+\varepsilon$, $\lim_{n}b_{n}$
exists. Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we obtain $l-\varepsilon\leq\lim_{n}b_{n}\leq l+\varepsilon$.
That is, $|\lim_{n}b_{n}-l|\leq\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon>0$
is arbitrary, we conclude that $|\lim_{n}b_{n}-l|=0$, i.e., $\lim_{n}a_{n}=\lim_{n}b_{n}$.

You proved that $(b_n)$ converges monotonically increasing to some $b \in \mathbb R$. This means in particular  that $b_n \le b$ for all $n$. Since $b_n \le a_n$, we know that $b \le a = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$.
Assume that $b < a$. There exists $N$ such that $\lvert a_n - a \rvert < \frac{a -b}{2}$ for $n \ge N$. Since $a - a_n \le \lvert a_n - a \rvert$, we see that
$$a - a_n < \frac{a -b}{2} \text{ for } n \ge N. \tag{1}$$
From $(1)$ we get
$$a_n > \frac{a+b}{2}  \text{ for } n \ge N. \tag{2}$$
Thus
$$b_N = \inf_{n \ge N} a_n \ge  \frac{a+b}{2} > b \text{ since } a > b .$$
This is a contradiction because $b_n \le b$ for all $n$.
